# PYTHON Symbol is not callable

Tags: python, symbols, differential-equations

I started to learn Python for differential and difference equations and this is from the SymPy tutorial, but still I get this error: `'Symbol' object is not callable.` How can I solve this problem?

```
t = symbols('t',real=True)

x, y = symbols('x, y', function=True)

eq = (Eq(Derivative(x(t),t), 12*t*x(t) + 8*y(t)), Eq(Derivative(y(t),t), 21*x(t) + 7*t*y(t)))
```

Comment: Might be you have used symbols as a variable somewhere

Comment: Is symbols from a module you loaded? Did you make this function? Did you make it a variable? There isn't enough information in your question to help.

Comment: But to try and help, what this error means is that the object 'symbols' is not a function, therefore it is not callable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I interpret the [docs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/index.html) correctly, your example should be defined as follows:

```
from sympy import Function

t = symbols('t',real=True)

x = Function('x')(t)
y = Function('y')(t)

eq = (Eq(Derivative(x,t), 12*t*x + 8*y), 
      Eq(Derivative(y,t), 21*x + 7*t*y))
```

[image]

Comment: Oh thanks, I am really bad at understanding this Python syntax. I know this was a simple question but I really appreciate it. Thank you so much, guys.

Comment: Ok, I just realized that such a thing exists. I have accepted it now, and Can I ask a question if you have time? I wanna only to learn Python in terms of economic dynamics so I only need differential and difference equations and plotting them and Do you think that Should I learn it from scratch?

Comment: @Tatanik501 If you are using python libraries like Sympy you will need to get familiar with python as a language to some extent. Otherwise you keep running into basic syntax problems. I'd suggest you follow some beginners online course or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Have a good day.